# Add a common legend to a partitioned plot

Tags: r, plot, legend, partition

I would like to make a partitioned plot in `R` with a common legend.

Here's an example data:

```
set.seed(1)
replicates <- 4
df <- data.frame(y = rep(rnorm(100),replicates), x = rep(rnorm(100),replicates),
                 replicate = c(sapply(1:replicates,function(x) rep(x,100))))


par(mfcol = c(4,4),
    mar = c(3,3,0.5,0.5), oma = rep(1,4))
for(i in 1:replicates){
  for(j in 1:replicates){
    plot(df$x[which(df$replicate == i)], df$x[which(df$replicate == j)], xlab = "", ylab = "")
    title(xlab = paste("replicate", i, sep = " "), ylab = paste("replicate", j, sep = " "), line = 2)
  }
}
```

The common legend, which I would like to appear at the bottom, should be:

```
legend(legend = "measurements", pch = 16, col = "gray")
```

Comment: For axis titles, `mtext(outer = TRUE` is a common solution. [Several posts on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=%5br%5d%20mtext%20outer%20true)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is there anything equivalent for a common legend?

Comment: I assume so. But "appear at the bottom" is not very clear. You should also show us what you have tried, other relevant posts, and why they don't work in your case.

Comment: Is the real output something you might want to replicate many times? If not a simple solution is to use locator() as this will allow you to click where you want it

Comment: Unfortunately I do want to replicate it many time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `layout`:

```
par(mar = c(3,3,0.5,0.5), oma = rep(1,4))
layout(rbind(matrix(1:16, 4), rep(17, 4)), heights = c(rep(1, 4), 0.5))
for(i in 1:replicates){
  for(j in 1:replicates){
    plot(df$x[which(df$replicate == i)], df$x[which(df$replicate == j)], xlab = "", ylab = "")
    title(xlab = paste("replicate", i, sep = " "), ylab = paste("replicate", j, sep = " "), line = 2)
  }
}
par(mar = c(0,0,0,0))
plot.new()
legend(x = "center", legend = "measurements", pch = 16, col = "gray")
```

[image: resulting plot]